# Why cordova-plugin-file is a so slow writer?

Tags: android, html, file, cordova

I'm working an Android app based on Cordova. Unfortunately I'm about to despair. My app should be able to handle attachments so I have to get files from the device and put them in my app directory. For this I use the HTML5 File API. I create a blob and pass it on to the Cordova File Plugin which then writes the file. My problem now is that writing the files is very slow. A file with 10MB takes a good 5 seconds and if it gets 50MB then I can wait almost 30 seconds. I also tried to use smaller chunks but the result is unfortunately the same.  I really need help because I need to get the problem under control. Couldn't be that the HTML5 File API or the Cordova File Plugin is just so slow.... All I've found is it's probably just that. That can't be!?

So thank you for your help.

Comment: "I use the HTML5 File API. I create a blob and pass it on to the Cordova File Plugin"  - Post that piece of code

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for your Answer. I use the folowing code...`// input type=file change handler
private readThis(inputValue: any): void {
  const t1 = performance.now();
  const file = inputValue.files[0];

  // cordova plugin file = this.file
  this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, file.name, file)
    .then(() => {
    const t2 = performance.now();
    // takes about 1s/MB
    console.log('writing took ' + (t2 - t1));
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    });
}`

Comment: This is not JavaScript.

Comment: I never said it was JavaScript. Its TypeScript!